# How to change the deprecated function NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:) to unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, deprecation-warning, nskeyedunarchiver

In my application, the user data getting after login is saved in the preferences as below. The xcode shows the warning that NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:) and NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:) are deprecated from iOS 12. But application is working fine till the latest iOS versions. To make it stable, how can I change it to unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: which is recommended.

```
static var userLoginResponse : LoginModel? {
        get {
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userLoginResponse"), let respData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Data {
                return LoginModel(data: respData)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue?.toJsonData() {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value), forKey: "userLoginResponse")
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "userLoginResponse")
            }
        }
    }
```

As per the apple documentation, unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:  will unarchive the data saved as NSCoded object. How can I change this existing implementation without affect the existing app users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the function by:

```
try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSData.self, from: data) as? Data
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to archive `Data` which is already PropertyList compliant. Remove the `NSKeyed(Un)archiver` stuff.

```
static var userLoginResponse : LoginModel? {
    get {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userLoginResponse") else { return nil }
        return LoginModel(data: data)
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.toJsonData(), forKey: "userLoginResponse")
    }
}
```

Side-note: Never use `setValue(_:forKey:)` unless you mean KVC (you don't).

Comment: That means we use NSKeyed(Un)archiver if want to save an object as such right?.

Comment: Only if you’ve got objects (`NSObject` classes) conforming to `NSCoding`. However nowadays prefer `Codable` whenever possible.

Comment: Here the LoginModel class is Codable but the wrong part is converting to Data and the use NSKeyedArchiver to save to preference. Am I right?. Since the application is used by large number of users and this userData is accessing every time they launch, will it affect the application if I change and update the app? This was developed years back.

Comment: once again you can save `Data` to `UserDefaults` directly. There is no need to archive it.